How to correctly use of precacheAndRoute to serve index.html?
My website is a single-page application, and Nginx uses try_files to return index.html for various routes. I've pre-cached index.html using Workbox. However, I've noticed that when I first visit a route, there is an initial document request, and then the service worker also makes another request for index.html. These are two different requests with different durations, and the service worker's fetch does not use the cache from the initial document request. Is this expected behavior? How can I fix this issue so that only one request is necessary?
nginx.conf:
     location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
            add_header Cache-Control "no-cache,max-age=0";

workbox-config.js:
module.exports = {
  globDirectory: 'dist',
  globPatterns: [
    'index.html',

service-worker.js:
...
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST || [])
...
registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => {
    if (request.destination === 'document') {
        ...
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
  },
  async ({ request }) => {
    const response = await matchPrecache(`/index.html`)
    if (response) {
      return response
    } else {
      return fetch(request)
    }
  }
)
...


